# UIView can't move after masking image

Tags: objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, cgcontext

I have a `UIView` with a `UIImage` property. I am masking that image and adding it to the `UIView`. Once I have clipped the mask to the image my gestures no longer work.

Masking Code:

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
... // Creating mask
CGContextClip(ctx);
[self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height)];
CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathStroke);
```

Gesture Code:

```
- (void)move:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gesture {  
    CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:self.superview];
    CGRect currentFrame = self.frame; 
    currentFrame.origin.x = self.frame.origin.x + translation.x;
    currentFrame.origin.y = self.frame.origin.y + translation.y;
    self.frame = currentFrame;
    [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.superview];
}
```

If I remove this line: `CGContextClip(ctx);` The gestures work just fine. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.